# Graphview dashed/dotted lines?

Tags: flutter

I would like to dynamically change the draw of a line from solid, dotted or dashed.
How to achieve this with [graphview](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview) flutter ?

Comment: try to fork the project and edit the custom paint line.